# Any way for Pandas to create and output corresponding to user's requests graphs, using input()?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a Pandas Dataframe which I got using parsing from IMDb. I want to be able to create and output certain barplots, corresponding to the users request from input().

```
   name      decade   genre
0  movie1    20s      adventure
1  movie2    20s      fantasy
... 
89 movie35   00s      drama
90 movie36   10s      sci-fi
```

For example, the input is '30', then the corresponding graph in range(10, 19) *(considering that df starts from the 20's and there're 10 movies in each decade)* pops up for the user. The code for the graph is below (oscar_df is the original df, can provide the parsing code):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

glo = []
from collections import Counter
for st in range(0, 10):
    for i in oscar_df['Genre'][st]:
            glo.append(i.strip())

os_df = pd.DataFrame(list(Counter(glo).items()), columns = ['G', 'Q'])
os_df.sort_values('G') 
os_df

ax = sns.barplot(x='Q',y='G', data=os_df, palette="hls", orient='h');
ax.set(xlabel='Number of Oscars', ylabel = None)
```

I was thinking of a fstring and a loop, and was searching a lot, but didn't find much. Any way to tackle this?

Comment: Are you looking for a user input function to define what to plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just posting a few tips for helpfulness.

I would recommend validating responses. You can use the `re` module (regular expressions) and just look for two digits in the input string.  The following snippet also has a while loop that will repeat until a desired response is entered:

```
import re

number_of_attempts = 3
while number_of_attempts > 0:
    dex = input('Enter two last digits of the decade (for instanse: 30): ')
    # Does the input contain two digits?
    if re.match(r"\d{2}", dex):
        # Break our loop by setting our variable to zero
        number_of_attempts = 0
    else:
        # Increment the variable lower by 1
        number_of_attempts -= 1
```

You can use .str.contains() to filter a DataFrame.  Then we can skip the 's' on the decade:

```
df_decade = oscar_df[oscar_df['decade'].str.contains(dex)]
# e.g. - df_decade = oscar_df[oscar_df['decade'].str.contains('30')]
```

Or, save time and just get the column you want:

```
df_decade_genre = oscar_df[oscar_df['decade'].str.contains(dex)]['genre']
```

Instead of importing Counter, you could use Series.value_counts().  Below, we set a category variable to 'genre' and then counted those results:

```
category = 'genre'
df_counts = df_decade[category].value_counts()
```

Finally, while not Seaborn, Pandas has a [plot feature](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) that you can call directly from a DataFrame or Series. This snippet doesn't use a dataframe, but you can use Pandas [.sort_values()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) function to order your series by ascending or descending order before plotting.

```
category = 'genre'
df_counts = df_decade[category].value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Get the top n values:

```
n = 10
df_top_n_count = df_decade[category].value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False)[:n]
```

And plot the results:

```
df_counts.plot(kind='bar') # Very rudimentary.
```

Or, use the dataframe and set x and y to your desired categories:

```
oscar_df.plot(x='genre', y='decade', kind='bar')
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Consider no loop or counter collection but simply filter rows by input and then run a `groupby` count:

```
dex = str(input('Enter two last digits of the decade (for instanse: 30): ')+'s') 

os_df = (oscar_df[oscar_df['Decade'] == dex]
            .reindex(['Genre', 'Decade'], axis = 1)
            .groupby(['Genre'], as_index = False)
            .count()
            .rename({'Decade':'Q', 'Genre':'G'})
        )

ax = sns.barplot(x='Q',y='G', data=os_df, palette="hls", orient='h') 
ax.set(xlabel='Amount of Academy Awards', ylabel = None)
plt.title('Stats for the decade you have chosen', 
          fontname='Helvetica', fontsize=18)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer myself, maybe not the most sophisticated one, though.

```
dex = str(input('Enter two last digits of the decade (for instanse: 30): ')+'s')

for i in range(len(oscar_df['Decade'])):
                    if (set(oscar_df['Decade'][i]) == set(dex)) == True:
                        for a in oscar_df['Genre'][i]:
                            glo.append(a.strip()) 

os_df = pd.DataFrame(list(Counter(glo).items()), columns = ['G', 'Q'])
    list.clear(glo)
    os_df.sort_values('G')     
    ax = sns.barplot(x='Q',y='G', data=os_df, palette="hls", orient='h')
    ax.set(xlabel='Amount of Academy Awards', ylabel = None);
    plt.title('Stats for the decade you have chosen', fontname='Helvetica',
         fontsize=18);
```